# How do I use SQL window to sum rows with a condition

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Assume this is my table:

```
id start_date   event_date     sales
------------------------------------
1   2020-09-09   2020-08-30     27.9
1   2020-09-09   2020-09-01     15
1   2020-09-09   2020-09-05     25
1   2020-09-09   2020-09-06     20.75
2   2020-09-09   2020-01-30     5
2   2020-09-09   2020-08-01     12
```

I'm trying to use a window function, where I want to sum sales in event_date for 7 days prior to the start date for each id, so the output I'm trying to reach looks like this...

```
id  start_date   event_date    sales   sales_7_days
-------------------------------------------------
1   2020-09-09   2020-08-30     27.9     0
1   2020-09-09   2020-09-01     15       0     <---- this is not within 7 days of start_date
1   2020-09-09   2020-09-05     25       25    <---- this is within 7 days of start_date
1   2020-09-09   2020-09-06     20.75    40.75 <---- this is within 7 days of start_date
2   2020-09-09   2020-01-30     5        0
2   2020-09-09   2020-09-03     12       12
```

This is what I've tried so far, but the problem is it seems to start summing from 7 days previous to event_date rather than start_date.

```
SELECT
   id,
   start_date,
   event_date,
   sales,
   CASE WHEN event_date >=  DATE_ADD(start_date, -7) THEN SUM(sales)  \
        OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY event_date RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) ELSE 0 END AS sales_7_days
FROM 
   sample_df
ORDER BY 
   id, 
   start_date,
   event_date
```

So the query above is producing the below (which I don't want, because the window sum starts from event_date rather than start_date)

```
id  start_date   event_date    sales   sales_7_days
-------------------------------------------------
1   2020-09-09   2020-08-30     27.9     0
1   2020-09-09   2020-09-01     15       0     
1   2020-09-09   2020-09-05     25       67.9    
1   2020-09-09   2020-09-06     20.75    60.75 
2   2020-09-09   2020-01-30     5        0
2   2020-09-09   2020-09-03     12       17
```

Does anybody have any tips here?

Comment: SparkSQL <> T-SQL.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  I am also lost on the arithmetic.  The data does not seem to match the results.  The start date is the same on all rows, but the sales are not the same.

Comment: The start date is meant to be the same, the idea being that I'm trying to sum sales in the event_date column 7 days prior to start_date. This is why the first two cells of sales_7_day in the desired output are 0. Please let me know if you require any more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where I want to sum sales in event_date for 7 days prior to the start date for each id

Because the start date is constant for each id, this is a constant.  You can calculate it as:

```
select s.*,
       sum(case when event_date <= start_date and event_date >=  start_date - interval 7 day
                then sales
           end) over (partition by id)
from sample_df s;
```

Your results suggest, though, that you really want a *cumulative* sum based on the `event_date`.  That's fine, but a different question.  The answer for that is to tweak the SQL:

```
select s.*,
       sum(case when event_date <= start_date and event_date >=  start_date - interval 7 day
                then sales
           end) over (partition by id order by event_date)
from sample_df s;
```